Не подсвечивается tf.keras
keras хоть и импортируется из библиотеки, код выполняется, но сам keras никак не подсвечивается, и подсказок для него нет, а так изучать библиотеку не очень удобно


возможно где-то и есть решение этой проблемы, но я не нашел

Добавьте версии всего в вопрос. TF, питона...

@CrazyElf все последней версии

а ой, а был уверен что все последней

Сегодня последняя, а завтра новая выйдет или послезавтра )
